# Access Google map api inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I used to access google api with

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

in the header of the HTML page

what happen if i have to use the google map api inside a java Script function only (.js) with no HTML such as

```
function getMap()
{
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

This java Script function would be executed base on the onSave event in the Microsoft Dynamic CRM online 2011

I did some research, do i have to use `document.write(...)` and create a html page to execute the java script?

Comment: What do you exactly trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to use Google Api to get the latitude and longitude for the address and save it to the CRM field

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Geocoding Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which is what it looks like you need.

Please verify that you comply with the Terms of Use (the resulting data must be displayed on a Google Map for both the web service and the javascript API)